# jQuery validation for HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate my form using jQuery Validation plugin. I want fire validation on tags like `<1>`, `<2`, But `<` or `>` need to allowed. Here is the code

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("htmlNoAllowed", function(value, element) {
    ///^<([a-z]+)([^<]+)*(?:>(.*)<\/\1>|\s+\/>)$/
    //return this.optional(element) || !((/^([a-z]+)<([a-z]+)([^<]+)*(?:(.*))$/).test(value));
    //return this.optional(element) || !((/<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>/).test(value));
    /*var re = new RegExp("<(.|\n)*", "g");
    return this.optional(element) || !(re.test(value));*/
    return this.optional(element) || !((/[<>]/).test(value));
}, "Letters only please"); 

$("#house_comment_post_frm").validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    errorClass : 'text-error',
    rules :{
        house_post_call:{
            required: true,
            htmlNoAllowed: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        house_post_call: {
            required: js_lang_Please_enter_message,
            htmlNoAllowed: js_lang_Please_not_used_the_html_tags
        }       
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            validator.errorList[0].element.focus(); //Set Focus
        }
    },      
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I need not to allowed <a, <a>,<a></a> tags. But allowed the > greater then or < less than